# Netted If Statement

Tags: excel

I need a formula to tell me whether a value in a specific cell is within a certain range.  The formula below keeps producing the output ">$75" even for numbers below 75K.  Can anyone help me out with this?  Thanks so much!

```
=IF(N2>100000,">$100K",IF(99999.99>N2>75000,">75K",IF(74999.99>N2>50000,">$50K",IF(49999.99>N2>30000,">$30K",IF(29999.99>N2>20000,">$20K",IF(19999.99>N2>10000,">$10K","<$10K"))))))
```

Comment: Simplify! I suggest you split this one formula into several columns worth of formulas.  It'll be easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I need it one column for the use in the rest of the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not allow the `99999.99>N2>75000`  It would be `AND(99999.99>N2, N2>75000)`

But you can simplify this to:

```
=INDEX({"<$10K",">$10k",">$20K",">$30K",">$50k",">$75k",">$100k"},MATCH(N2,{0,10000,20000,30000,50000,75000,100000}))
```

If you really want the IF, then realize that IF resolves in order and the AND talked about above is not needed.

```
=IF(N2>100000,">$100K",IF(N2>75000,">75K",IF(N2>50000,">$50K",IF(N2>30000,">$30K",IF(N2>20000,">$20K",IF(N2>10000,">$10K","<$10K"))))))
```

If you have Office 365 you can use IFS():

```
=IFS(N2>100000,">$100K",N2>75000,">75K",N2>50000,">$50K",N2>30000,">$30K",N2>20000,">$20K",N2>10000,">$10K",N2<=10000,"<$10K")
```